# How to get time in 10H:30M format, Hour and minute should be denoted with H and M - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have converted minutes into HH:mm:ss with `str(timedelta(minutes=total_minutes))`

It gives me time like 10:30:44,

I want output like this 10H:30M, Is there any method in time/datetime module which does that or should I go with splitting this string and appending H and M.

Comment: Are you sure about the colon?  It is redundant if you have 10H30M.

Comment: I am fine with that if it doesn't have colon, it there any short way/ pre built method to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the deltatime and format a string on the desired format.

```
import datetime

total_minutes = 5000 #For example

time = datetime.timedelta(minutes=total_minutes)
formattedStr = '{}H:{}M'.format(time.seconds // 3600, (time.seconds // 60) % 60)

print(formattedStr)
```

Comment: have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

You can import and use strftime, which allows you to do many things with time & date  https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
x = strftime("%HH:%MM", gmtime())    
print(x)
```

Output `04H:27M`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> x = timedelta(minutes=63)
>>> f'{x.seconds // 3600}H:{(x.seconds % 3600) // 60}M'
'1H:3M'
```